# SQL query to pick the last entry with a condition

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

I am trying to query the data where I need to pick those data whose last event is 3 in condition1 and 4 in condition2 and the last event should be within the month of January.

The data is as below,

```
col1    condition1  condition2  date
1234    0              1        01/01/2020  
1234    1              2        02/01/2020  
1234    2              3        04/01/2020  
1234    3              4        10/01/2020  
5678    0              1        25/01/2020  
5678    1              2        26/01/2020  
5678    2              3        28/01/2020  
5678    3              4        03/02/2020  
8901    0              1        17/01/2020  
8901    1              2        18/01/2020  
8901    2              3        20/01/2020  
8901    3              4        22/01/2020  
8901    4              5        24/01/2020  
8901    5              6        26/01/2020  
3467    0              1        13/01/2020  
3467    1              2        15/01/2020  
3467    2              3        16/01/2020  
3467    3              4        24/01/2020  
3467    4              5        27/01/2020  
3467    5              6        28/01/2020
```

Expected Output

```
col1    condition1  condition2  date
1234    3              4        10/01/2020
```

Comment: Column date data type?

Comment: Are you using Teradata?

Comment: yes using Teradata

Comment: column date with Date Data type (example: date '2020-01-01')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from mytable
qualify
   rank()
   over (partition by col1
         order by datecol desc) = 1 -- last event
-- additional conditions
and datecol between date '2021-01-01' and date '2021-01-31'
and condition1 = 3
and condition2 = 4;
```

Comment: Nice! I'm not a Teradata guy, and I wasn't aware of the qualify clause. Interesting.

Comment: @jarlh: QUALIFY is similar to WHERE/HAVING, applying filter conditions *after* calculating a *Windowed Aggregate*. Nice to have as it avoids a Derived Table/CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Translate "*...pick the last entry with a condition [...]
whose last event is 3 in condition1 and 4 in condition2 and the last event should be within the month of January.*" to SQL:

```
SELECT col1, condition1, condition2, "date"
FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE condition1 = 3 AND condition2 = 4
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "date") = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename AS t2
                  WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    AND t2."date" > t1."date")
```

BTW, `DATE` is a Teradata reserved word (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words). If you have a column with that name, it must be delimited as `"date"`.

**Edit:** "*sorry, I forgot to mention the year:( it should extract data for the month January and year 2020.*"

```
SELECT col1, condition1, condition2, "date"
FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE condition1 = 3 AND condition2 = 4
  AND "date" BETWEEN DATE'2021-01-01' AND DATE'2021-01-31'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename AS t2
                  WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    AND t2."date" > t1."date")
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention the year:( it should extract data for the month January and year 2020.